# Execute token after \halign

Tags: macros, tables, horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

I like to create a macro which processes a following brace group as "argument" using `\halign`. After it has been processed a token (a macro) should be executed. With an `\hbox` I can use `\aftergroup\mytoken` direct after the opening brace to execute something after the closing brace. However, this doesn't work with `\halign` because every cell it is own group and `\aftergroup` would place something in the next cell.
I also had the idea to have some recursive `\aftergroup` macro which places itself always in the next cell until the last cell is reached. But this would break any `\noalign` code added after a `\cr` (or `\\` in LaTeX), beside being tricky in the first place.

Is there any way to use `\afterassignment`, `\aftergroup` or any other way to execute a macro after the `}` of `\halign`? Alternatively placing a `\egroup` before it and use the `}` as end of an outer group would also be fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mytab{%
    \afterassignment\dotab
    \let\dummy=%
}
\def\dotab{%
    \AFTERHALIGN\dosomethingafterwards
    \halign\bgroup
        \hfil\ignorespaces##\unskip\cr
}
\def\dosomethingafterwards{...}

\begin{document}

\mytab{%
    A \cr
    B \cr
    C \cr
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: it's tough, and perhaps impossible to provide a fully robust solution since finding out whether a given cr is the last one is very difficult: after a `\cr`, TeX scans ahead, ignoring spaces (at least plain (32,10) ones) and `\crcr`, and expanding everything else, except eTeX's protected control sequences, until finding a non-expandable token. TeX then inserts the template, except in the following cases:

- `\noalign` starts a new group inserted between lines of the tabular
- `\omit` starts the cell normally, but without inserting the template
- a catcode 2 token (closing brace or `\egroup`) ends the `\halign`.

Two more things I can think of which interact with what TeX is doing there are `\aftergroup` and `\everycr`. After a `\cr` (or a non-redundant `\crcr`, i.e., one that is not ignored by TeX scanning ahead after a `\cr`), the content of `\everycr` are inserted, immediately followed by `\aftergroup`-ed tokens, and then the following characters in the file. The resulting token list is read by TeX as I explained, expanding as it goes, ignoring spaces and `\crcr`.

We thus need to detect closing braces after any `\cr`. This requires a non-expandable `\futurelet`, which as you say breaks the `\noalign` mechanism. The solution is along the lines of `\everycr{\noalign\bgroup\test}`, where `\test` checks what the next token is, then closes the `\noalign` group (it will insert a height-zero vertical box in the page, but I think that that changes nothing to the output.

Code. The easiest way I can think of is to use the `\everycr` token parameter. I'm using eTeX's `\currentgrouplevel` to only insert the special bit of `\noalign` for `\cr` which appear in the outer table, not nested tables. The external group is not really needed either (just to keep changes to `\everycr` local). The main idea is that after each `\cr`, a `\noalign\bgroup\futurelet...` is inserted to check if that was the last cr (it was if we find a closing brace). This probably has bad interactions with redundant/non-redundant `\crcr`, and also has other drawbacks, I would guess. I commented out the `` \romannumeral-\`0 ``: it is useful if you fear that the last `\cr` won't be immediately followed by the closing brace.

```
\def\mytab{%
    \begingroup
    \everycr\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\mytabcr
        \the\expandafter\currentgrouplevel\expandafter;%
        \the\everycr}%
    \afterassignment\dotab
    \let\dummy=%
}
\def\dotab{%
    \halign\bgroup
        \hfil\ignorespaces##\unskip\cr
}
\def\mytabcr#1;{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#1-2=\currentgrouplevel %not sure about that 2
        \noalign\bgroup
            \expandafter\mytabcrX %\romannumeral-`0%
    \fi}
\def\mytabcrX{\futurelet\mytabcrtoken\mytabcrtest}
\def\mytabcrtest{%
    \ifcat\noexpand\mytabcrtoken\egroup
        \aftergroup\mytabcrend
    \else
        \egroup
    \fi}
\def\mytabcrend{\egroup\dosomethingafter\endgroup}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, the idea to detect the `}` after the line break seems to be the way to go. I now implemented something like this for my `collectbox` package. I decided to go with LaTeX `tabular` style instead and redefined ``\\`` accordantly. To avoid issues with inner `tabular`s I redefine `\ialign` to reset ``\\``. See [the code](http://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/collectbox/diff/collectbox.sty?diff2=7d5a82b57aa8&diff1=06c01bd8f096) for details if you are interested. Now, `adjustbox` has a `tabular`, `tabular*` and `array` keys for both environment and macro-mode.